# How does the Jenkins CloudBees Docker Build Plugin set its Shell Path

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm working with a Jenkins install I've inherited.  This install has the [CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Custom+Build+Environment+Plugin) installed.  We *think* this plugin gives us a nifty *Build inside a Docker container* checkbox in our build configuration.  When we configure jobs with this option, it looks like (based on Jenkins console output) Jenkins runs the build with the following command

```
Docker container 548ab230991a452af639deed5eccb304026105804b38194d98250583bd7bb83q started to host the build
[WIP-Tests] $ docker exec -t 548ab230991a452af639deed5eccb304026105804b38194d98250583bd7bb83q /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7939624860798651072.sh
```

However -- we've found that this runs `/bin/sh` with a very limited set of environmental variables -- including a `$PATH` that doesn't include `/bin`!  So

1. How does the *CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin* setup its `/bin/sh` environment. Is this user configurable via the UI (if so, where?)
2. It looks like Jenkins is using `docker exec` -- which *i think* means that it must have (invisibly) setup a container with a long running process using `docker run`.  Doesn't anyone know how the *CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin* plugin invokes `docker run`, and if this is user manageable?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this plugin is "up for adoption", I would recommend the official [JENKINS/Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin).

It [source code show very few recent commits](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-custom-build-environment-plugin/commits/master).

But don't forget any container [has a default entrypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564990/6309) set to `/bin/sh`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

Then:

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/78676506/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202015-06-25%20%C3%A0%2018.07.49.png?version=1&modificationDate=1435248491000&api=v2]

> The docker container is ran after SCM has been checked-out into a slave workspace, then all later build commands are executed within the container thanks to `docker exec` introduced in Docker 1.3

That means the image you will be pulling or building/running must have a shell, to allow the `docker exec` to execute a command in it.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the tip on the Pipeline plugin -- politics may prevent that from being used on this specific project, but it sounds like something I might be able to use on a future project.  Also, thank you for the info on docker exec.  Per the original question, we are aware that jenkins uses docker exec  -- however, in order for docker exec to work there needs to be an already running, not exiting container -- we're ultimately interested in knowing how the cloudbees plugin kicks all that off.